# SQL Server 2012 Geospatial Queries

Tags: sql-server, geospatial

I have a SQL Server 2012 table I'm starting to put together that contains location data. The schema looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HotSpot](
    [eBirdCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CountryCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CountryStateCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CountryStateCountyCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Latitude] [numeric](18, 5) NULL,
    [Longitude] [numeric](18, 5) NULL,
    [HotSpotName] [varchar](250) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a great deal of experience with SQL Server but absolutely none using its geospatial features. What I would like to be able to accept a latitude / longitude coordinate and a distance (miles or kilometers) from a user and execute a query that returns all rows in the table whose latitude and longitude coordinates are within that range.

For example, a user might provide a coordinate of 28.16842 /-82.84704 and say 20 miles. I'd like to return all rows in the table that are within 20 miles of that coordinate. And, if possible, the number of miles each point is from the target point.

First, can the geospatial features in SQL Server do something like this? Second, any advice on how to get started learning how to do this? At the moment, I'm not interested in learning all the geospatial functionality in SQL Server. I just need to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. The following is an example. I added a persisted computed column to my table to use as the Geography point. Note: before a spatial index can be added, the table must have a clustered index and the computed column must be persisted.

```
-- Add the computed, persisted column to represent the Geography point
Alter Table dbo.HotSpot Add Coordinate as Geography::STGeomFromText('POINT('+convert(varchar(20),Longitude)+' '+convert(varchar(20),Latitude)+')',4326) PERSISTED

-- Add the spatial index
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX IX_HotSpot_Coordinate ON dbo.HotSpot (Coordinate)

-- Now an example how to use this. 
-- STDistance() returns distances in the linear unit of measure of the spatial reference system in which your geography data is defined. 
-- We're using SRID 4326, which means that STDistance() returns distances in metres. 1609.344 metres = 1 mile


Declare @Latitude numeric(18,6) = 41.605880485097465
Declare @Longitude numeric(18,6) = -83.71285647153854
Declare @pt GEOGRAPHY = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST(@Longitude AS Varchar(40))+ ' ' + CAST(@Latitude AS Varchar(40)) + ')', 4326);
Declare @MaxDistance Int = 20 -- Miles

Select dbo.HotSpot.*, @pt.STDistance(Coordinate) / 1609.344 AS Distance
From dbo.HotSpot 
WHERE Coordinate.STDistance(@pt) < (20 * 1609.344)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNearestHotSpots (
     @lat       FLOAT
    ,@lon       FLOAT
    ,@maxdist   FLOAT  -- in English statute miles
    ,@N         INT
)AS
BEGIN
    declare @MaxDistMetres float = @maxDist * 1609.344;
    DECLARE @pt GEOGRAPHY = geography::STGeomFromText(
                                       'POINT(' + CAST(@lat AS Varchar(20))
                                          + ' ' + CAST(@lon AS Varchar(20)) + ')', 
                                  4326);

    -- return dataset 
    SELECT HotSpotName, @pt.STDistance(Geography) AS dist
    FROM (
        select 
            HotSpotName,
            geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + cast(Latitude as varchar(20)) 
                                         + ' ' + cast(Longitude as varchar(20)) + ')',
                       4326) as Geography
        from dbo.HotSpot
    ) t
    WHERE Geography.STDistance(@pt) < @MaxDistMetres 

    ORDER BY dist;
END;
go
```

As I understand the SRID ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933887.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964707(v=sql.110).aspx) - the 4326 parameter in both conversion calculations above) it is a reference type for pre-defined Geometry types, and must be identical for objects being compared. It specifies that distances are to be returned in metes.

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to set up my table in any certain way? Or have spatial indexes set up (I read something about spatial indexes I think)?

Comment: @RandyMinder: The Geography calculated column in the subquery could be added to your table definition as a computed column. This column then could be added to a spatial index in order to speed up queries, but wouldn't be essential until you had a significant number of hotspots. I am still just learning this as well, so can't speak much more on that yet.

Comment: Pieter - I've had a chance to research this a bit and there are a number of problems with your response. I posted an answer to my own question that might be of help to you (and others).

Comment: @RandyMinder: Corrected. Thank you.  In your answer I think you could eliminate the join on eBirdCode by replacing eBirdCode with HotSpot.* in the CTE.

Comment: Yes, you're right. And thanks for the initial suggestion. That sort of got the wheels turning in the right direction. This is an incredibly powerful feature of SQL Server that I knew existed but never had a need for it, until now.

Comment: I simplified my solution somewhat, added a computed and persisted column, then put a spatial index on it.